# how to call start capture method in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ipad, camera

I am capturing video in iphone app. I want to run below delegate method when user starts capturing video. It does not get call automatically. Any idea how to call this method?

```
- (BOOL)startVideoCapture
{
     timeLabel.text=@"Video is added";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Method like this : `[self startVideoCapture];`

**One Question :** `Return` type of this Method is `BOOL`. Don't you think, it should `return` some `BOOL` Value ?

Comment: if i will call this method my self how would i know user has start cpature then i call this method

Comment: @JamDev: You are on the wrong path. Take a look at this Tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

Comment: @JamDev: Was that useful to you ? If yes then "Accept" and "Up-vote" the Answer.